How to write two geopandas dataframes as layers of a .gpkg file in memory in python?
Currently, to save a geopackage to Google Cloud storage I have to first create and save each layer locally. I would like to write it memory and the copy from memory to GCS. I'm stuck on the writing to memory bit.
My current method is to run the code below and then copy the local file.
gdf1.to_file(local_file, layer='layer1', driver='GPKG')
gdf2.to_file(local_file, layer='layer2', driver='GPKG')

Is it possible to write these gdfs to .gpkg memoryfile?

https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

I haven't looked into doing this "properly" in any detail (i.e. using something like io.BytesIO(), see this issue), but here is a dirty workaround that uses gdal and its virtual ("VSI*") filesystems directly:
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from osgeo import gdal

##########################################################################################
# Make some dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['name1', 'name2'], 'wkt': ['POINT (1 2)', 'POINT (2 1)']})
gdf1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df['wkt']), crs="EPSG:4326")
gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df['wkt']), crs="EPSG:4326")
##########################################################################################

mem_file = "/vsimem/some_unique_name.gpkg"

# write GDFs to an in-memory gpkg
gdf1.to_file(mem_file, layer='layer1', driver='GPKG')
gdf2.to_file(mem_file, layer='layer2', driver='GPKG')

# Use GDAL API to read out the raw bytes from the in-memory gpkg

# get file size
file_size = gdal.VSIStatL(mem_file, gdal.VSI_STAT_SIZE_FLAG).size

# open file
vsi_file = gdal.VSIFOpenL(mem_file, 'r')

# read entire file
gpkg_bytes = gdal.VSIFReadL(1, file_size, vsi_file)

# Try writing gpkg_bytes to GCS

##########################################################################################
# Write it out, just to prove that it's a valid .gpkg, but you don't need to do this.
with open("test.gpkg", "wb") as output:
    output.write(gpkg_bytes)

test_gdf1 = gpd.read_file("test.gpkg", layer="layer1")
test_gdf2= gpd.read_file("test.gpkg", layer="layer2")
test_gdf1.head()
test_gdf2.head()
##########################################################################################

Alternatively, you may wish to look into writing directly to GCS using GDALs /vsigs/ virtual filesystem, something like output_gpkg = "/vsigs/your_bucket/path/to/output/gpkg" . I don't have a GCS account so can't test or provide a more complete example.
